# URL Rewriting subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'll be quick on what im trying to do,

basically I have a user profile page that will be my url, let's say,

```
profile.php?user=alex
```

So now what is working fine in my .htaccess file is changing that into

```
 website.com/alex
```

for quicker access.

For other purpose, I would need that to be basically

```
 alex.website.com
```

but I couldnt figure out a way to rewrite my URL to that, instead of having a subdomain for every user.

If you have any idea if it's possible & how I would go on doing this, I would appreciate it alot!

Thank you

Alex

Answer (score 1):

To just rewrite the URL path, try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^[a-z]+$ profile.php?user=$0
```

If your user names have a different syntax, replace `[a-z]` as you need.

For rewriting the host, try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ profile.php?user=%1
```

Note that this will only rewrite `//alex.example.com/` internally to `//alex.example.com/profile.php?user=alex`. Additionally, your server will already need to be configured that it accepts any subdomain of your domain (see [`ServerAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias) and [name-based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html)).